# Are there good online videos for Combinatorics?

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, online-resources

I am currently reading through "Walk Through Combinatorics" and encountered some difficult concepts and was wondering if there were online videos/lectures/courses that would help in learning the material.

Comment: I have heard that the book *generatingfunctionology* by Wilf is pretty lucid (although I have not read it myself).

Answer (score 0):

A simple google search results in many good resources. For example Khan academy : https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/pixar/crowds/crowds-1/v/intro-crowds
If you have any specific questions about the material, now thats when you should post here :)
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You could try [these](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL-XzhVrXIVeSi7xym1XAfFIxOAaHVhjtP) for enumerative combinatorics, [these](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLo4jXE-LdDTRXnkxZ7_SrOqo2lx41ww2j) and [these](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL4_hYwCyhAvZz_QANqcx80Wt_dgD8VTS1) for extremal combinatorics, maybe [these](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLJ5C_6qdAvBF0v3uOhAeDbuCv-Qq9xKj5) for graph theory